# <relativePath /> in <parent> section of pom.xml

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

Is `<relativePath>` tag used only in child's `pom.xml` to refer it's parent `pom.xml`? Can the tag be used for something else?

Also, is it used only in `child pom.xml` or it can be used in `parent pom.xml` also?

I have gone through documentation but it is confusing.

Comment: This question is unclear. Please try to explain it more thoroughly.

Comment: Have you tried to read official documentation?

Comment: Updated question